# A Java Class Invoking A Method

Tags: android

This is NetworkUtils.class

```
public class NetworkUtils {
final static String GITHUB_BASE_URL =
        "https://api.github.com/search/repositories";

final static String PARAM_QUERY = "q";
final static String PARAM_SORT = "sort";
final static String sortBy = "stars";

public static URL buildUrl(String githubSearchQuery) {
    Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(GITHUB_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(PARAM_QUERY, githubSearchQuery)
            .appendQueryParameter(PARAM_SORT, sortBy)
            .build();

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return url;
}
```

This is MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mSearchBoxEditText;
private TextView mUrlDisplayTextView;
private TextView mSearchResultsTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSearchBoxEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_search_box);
    mUrlDisplayTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_url_display);
    mSearchResultsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_github_search_results_json);
}

    private void makeGithubSearchQuery() {

    String githubQuery = mSearchBoxEditText.getText().toString();
    URL githubSearchUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrl(githubQuery)
    mUrlDisplayTextView.setText(githubSearchUrl.toString());
    String githubSearchResults = null;
    try {
        githubSearchResults = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(githubSearchUrl);
        mSearchResultsTextView.setText(githubSearchResults);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // TODO (4) Create a new GithubQueryTask and call its execute method, passing in the url to query
}
```

Notice that MainActivity.class uses this code.

```
URL githubSearchUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrl(githubQuery)
```

and the NetworkUtils.class uses this code.

```
public static URL buildUrl(String githubSearchQuery)
```

I do believe that 
`NetworkUtils.buildUrl(githubQuery)` is referring to `buildUrl(String githubSearchQuery)` and it is really confusing. I understand that the value of githubQuery will be the input from `mSearchBoxEditText.getText().toString();`, and now I'm wondering what would be the value of `String githubSearchQuery`, where would it come from??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2 Java Class Using Same Method With Differences

Actually the title itself is a huge mistake.
They are not same method with differences. The one you can find in `NetworkUtils` is the actual **definition** of the method. In `MainActivity`, You are just invoking it.

When you calls a method, the the control goes to the definition. Also a copy of arguments are passed to it(Note that in case of objects, a copy of the reference is passed, not a copy of the actual object. So any change affects in both sides). From the definition part, you can access it with a the new name.

> but isnt that githubQuery is in private class?

It is not private. It is a local, means it has lesser scope than private. However, it isn't going to be a problem as long as you have a reference.

Comment: Oh I see thank you very much! I am totally new to this, I'm a nurse.. lol this is getting crazy

Answer (score 0):

The value of **githubSearchQuery** will be the same as **githubQuery** as its being used to call **buildUrl(String githubSearchQuery)** method.

Comment: but isn't that `githubQuery` is in privateclass? how could `githubSearchQuery` take the value of `githubQuery`?